# Querying the total Path distance from this mySQL table

Tags: mysql, distance

I have this table, SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dd22) base from this image [image: path]

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
`id` INT( 11 ),
`Segment` VARCHAR( 5 ),
`Distance` FLOAT( 5, 2 ),
`startX` FLOAT( 5, 2 ),
`startY` FLOAT( 5, 2 ),
`endX` FLOAT( 5, 2 ),
`endY` FLOAT( 5, 2 )
);
INSERT INTO Table1 
(`id`, `Segment`, `Distance`, `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY`)
VALUES
(1, 'AB', 14.00, -20.00, -19.00, -34.00, -19.00),
(2, 'BC', 15.56, -9.00, -8.00, -20.00, -19.00),
(3, 'CD', 19.00, 10.00, -8.00, -9.00, -8.00),
(4, 'DE', 21.00, 10.00, -29.00, 10.00, -8.00),
(5, 'EF', 11.31, 18.00, -37.00, 10.00, -29.00),
(6, 'FG', 26.66, 42.00, -37.00, 18.00, -37.00),
(7, 'DH', 43.00, 53.00, -8.00, 10.00, -8.00),
(8, 'HI', 22.63, 69.00, -24.00, 53.00, -8.00),
(9, 'HJ', 13.00, 53.00, 5.00, 53.00, -8.00),
(10, 'JK', 14.14, 63.00, 15.00, 53.00, -5.00),
(11, 'KL', 21.00, 84.00, 15.00, 63.00, 15.00),
(12, 'LM', 14.14, 94.00, 25.00, 84.00, 15.00);
```

in the table the length of each segment were already given, start xy and end xy of the segment

question#1, is it possible to have a query using mysql from this table that will give me the total path distance, say if i want to get the path distance from point A to E will give me total distance AB+BC+CD+DE

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about iterating through different possibilities. While you could do that in MySQL (probably through some sort of procedure or function), it isn't a task that you would generally use SQL to do, it would normally be done on the app side.

If the number of points isn't very large (your example has 13), I would just build out a table of all tuples of points and then query for whichever two you are interested in.

```
CREATE TABLE distances (
  point1 VARCHAR(1),
  point2 VARCHAR(1),
  distance FLOAT(5,2)
);
```

Fill in your starting points (all the 1 segment ones you have provided) then do something along the lines of this:

```
INSERT INTO distances (point1, point2, distance) 
SELECT
  p1.point1 as point1,
  p2.point2 as point2,
  p1.distance + p2.distance as distance
FROM
  distances p1
INNER JOIN distances p2
  ON p1.point2 = p2.point1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(distance) 
  FROM table1 a  
 WHERE a.segment IN ('AB','BC','CD','DE');
```

I expect you could write a bit of code to build the IN string dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I am reasonably certain it's not possible to do this with a simple SQL query.  If your structure is always a tree you need to walk the path from the end node to the root, if not, you need to use something like Djikstra's algorithm.  Both solutions need an iterative process which isn't possible with SQL.  You might be able to do it with a stored procedure, but you're probably better off doing it in the script you're calling this from.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for. I am using Char operations determine the start and end of your path based on two inputs. the first Char of the starting point and the second Char of the end point.

```
SELECT SUM(t.distance) FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.segment >= CONCAT('A',Char(ASCII('A')+1))
AND t.segment <= CONCAT(Char(ASCII('E')-1),'E')
```

Comment: This solution is wrong. You can easily verify that by taking another example like A to M, in which case it will try to include all segments, such as DE and FG which are not part of the path.